# SignUp using Google Android Auth 2.0 HTTP post request after getting authorization code

Tags: java, android, http-post, oauth-2.0, google-account

```
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp
```

I am giving user to signup with Google account in webview with the following link

```
webview.loadUrl("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile&state=%2F&response_type=code&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&client_id=706645665586.apps.googleusercontent.com");
```

which contain my client id and redirect URI as per given by Google API console i.e  Choosing a Redirect URI
    https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp

and finally a get the authorization code that is returned in the title bar of the browser using view.getTitle()

Afterwards Another Request is required to send 
The actual request might look like:

```
POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: accounts.google.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
code=4/y_jtre05wvb6QSPo0Tkx5AbLfWB
client_id=706645665586.apps.googleusercontent.com
client_secret={client_secret}&
redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
grant_type=authorization_code
```

So Now while making HTTP POST request ..

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpcl = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpp = new HttpPost("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth");
    List<NameValuePair> a = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    a.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code", "4/y_jtre05wvb6QSPo0Tkx5AbLfWB"));
    a.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", "706645665586.apps.googleusercontent.com"));
    try {
        StringEntity mEntity = new StringEntity("");
        mEntity.setContentType(" application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        httpp.setEntity(mEntity);
        httpp.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(a));
        HttpResponse response1 = httpcl.execute(httpp);

        String response = EntityUtils.toString(response1.getEntity());
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So I am getting Bad Token response ... I am try this since yesterday and suggestion and help would be appreciated .. **my main aim is to get user info using gmail account in android**

Comment: Just to make sure: you're generating a new authorization code each time and the hardcoded one here is only for demonstration purposes?

Comment: Yeah i am generating always a fresh one ... and calling this method after my webview page finished .....ie onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) called

Comment: And you're also adding `client_secret`, `redirect_uri`, and `grant_type` to `a`, right? Then I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code. You could maybe try the recently launched [Google Play Services](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2012/09/google-play-services-and-oauth-identity.html) to handle OAuth (also in a more secure way) for you. Once you have an access token from it, you can then use Google's [OAuth2 API library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#oauth2) to get a `Userinfo` object.

Comment: As per their documentation client secret is not needed for when application is from mobile device ie in API console only gives client id , redirect URI ........

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing the different flows here a bit:

- The [Client-side flow](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent) **does not** require a **client secret**, but is primarily meant for Javascript applications.
- The [Installed Applications flow](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp) **does** require a **client secret**, though:

  > The client_id and client_secret obtained during registration are embedded in the source code of your application. In this context, the client_secret is obviously not treated as a secret.

  You probably generated a **client ID** in the [API console](https://code.google.com/apis/console#access) for *Installed application -> Android*, so you only got a **client ID** and had to specify your application's **certificate fingerprint**. This type of **client ID** is meant for use with the recently released and recommended (because it's more secure) [Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/google-play-services/).

  If you want to use the *Installed Applications flow* manually, you have to generate a **client ID** for *Installed application -> Other*, where you also get a **client secret**. When exchanging the **authorization code** for an **access token**, you are then required to specify all five parameters:

  ```
  code            The authorization code returned from the initial request
  client_id       The client_id obtained during application registration
  client_secret   The client secret obtained during application registration
  redirect_uri    The URI registered with the application
  grant_type      As defined in the OAuth 2.0 specification, this field must contain a value of authorization_code
  ```

Comment: So How do I get client_secret ID and grant_type for installed application ie in Android I have  only client_id and redirect_uri given in API console.

Comment: Click on "Create another client ID...", check "Installed application", check "Other", click on "Create client ID". Then you get a new `client_id` and a `client_secret`. `grant_type` has to be the fixed value `authorization_code`.

Comment: Thank i will try but that client_id will not refer to installed application it only meant for web application for respective client_secret

Comment: You have to create a **new** client id for an *installed application* of the type *other*!

Comment: I tried all this but not get any success and finally i got working example. Google has been changing the authentication process since long time .

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the working sample 
You can use Google+ developers API. Look at this project on [github](https://github.com/imellon/Google-Plus-Android-Sample) and this article.[here](http://www.imellon.com/blog/2011/11/24/integrating-google-api-to-android/)